# Check if the product of two consecutive list numbers equals another number

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

The code prints out 2 and 3 because their product equals the variable num. But what if l=[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]? No numbers in the list multiplied equal 6,so I'd like to print the two closest ones.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
num=6
index=0
while index+1<len(l):
   if l[index]*l[index+1]==num:
      print(l[index],l[index+1])
   index+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an easy expression with `min`:

First we use `zip` to build an iterator for consecutive elements: `zip(l, l[1:])`

Then we use `min` with the `key` being the distance from `num`:

```
min(zip(l, l[1:]), key = lambda x: abs(x[0]*x[1]-num))
```

If `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Output:

```
(2, 3)
```

If `l = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Output:

```
(1, 3)
```

If you want to get more outputs consider using `sorted` in the same manner to get a ranking:

```
sorted(zip(l, l[1:]), key = lambda x: abs(x[0]*x[1]-num))
```

If `l = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
```

If `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the index for the pair whose product is closest to `num` you can do:

#### Code:

```
min((abs(x*y - num), i) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])))[1]
```

#### Say what?

This uses a generator expression and `min()` to find the pair whose product is closest to num.  In that chain is:

```
zip(l, l[1:])
```

which produces a tuple for each neighbor pair.  Then `enumerate` is used to also produce the index.  Then the absolute value of the product - num is passed to `min()`

Comment: @Primusa, That is true, it is however a trivial extension to turn the index into a pair...